# How to load an integer value to a double register in MIPS?

Tags: mips

I have this code :

```
void test(int x)
 {
    cout<<x;
    double y=x+4.0;
    cout<<y;
 }
void main ()
 {
   test(7); // call the test in main 
 }
```

In MIPS :
after I put the value of parameter x in 0($fp) in stack and jump to test :

```
lw $a0,0($fp) // load value of x and print it
li $v0,1       
syscall

lw $t1,0($fp)
sw $t1,0($sp)  // put the value of x in stack and point it by $sp

li.d $f0,4.0
s.d $f0,4($sp) // put the value 4.0 in stack and point it by $sp

l.d $f0,0($sp)
l.d $f2,4($sp)
add.d $f4,$f0,$f2

s.d $f4,8($sp) // put the result of add 

l.d $f12,8($sp) // print the value of y 
li $v0,3
syscall
```

My problem is the result of y in QTSPIM is 4 .... the problem because I load an integer value in a double register ... How I can solve this problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the integer value into an fp register and then convert it to floating point format.  You have an 8-byte load (which will load the 4 bytes of your value, plus the following 4 bytes, whatever they happen to be), so you probably want to change that, and then do a cvt:

```
l.w $f0,0($fp)
cvt.d.w  $f0,$f0
```